# How to create proxy from ssh to connect with requests and sshtunnel

Tags: python, ssh, python-requests

This is my code

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import requests
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (MY_IP, 22),
    ssh_username=MY_USERNAME,
    ssh_password=MY_PASSWORD,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5555)
)

server.start()

print(server.local_bind_port)
# work with `SECRET SERVICE` through `server.local_bind_port`.
print requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:"+str(server.local_bind_port))
server.stop()
```

And i get error

```
2016-03-24 12:35:32,864 | ERROR   | Secsh channel 0 open FAILED: : Connect failed
2016-03-24 12:35:32,866 | ERROR   | In #1 <-- ('127.0.0.1', 50448) to ('127.0.0.1', 5555) failed: ChannelException(2, 'Connect failed')
```

How to make it become proxy

Comment: from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import requests
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('97.79.140.195', 22),
    ssh_username="admin",
    ssh_password="admin",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5555)
)

server.start()

print(server.local_bind_port)
# work with `SECRET SERVICE` through `server.local_bind_port`.
print requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:"+str(server.local_bind_port))
server.stop()

Comment: You should not put your login details for a publicly available server onto Stack Overflow (or anywhere on the internet). Please delete your comment. If you want to update your question, you can edit it directly.